# doctrine:schema:generate produces empty dump

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a bundle and so far, tried to separate Entities from an ORM.

What I've done so far is to create adequate services for managers and it works fine.

But there's an issue I'm struggling with: in `NS\TestBundle\Model` I've created abstract model classes which are mapped using XML files as *mapped-superclass*.

Then, I created some entities in `NS\TestBundle\Entity` which inherit after these Models.

And it works fine until I want to sync my Models with database.

`app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql`

produces just a `;`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a shame of mine: master-superclasses simply cannot be dumped because their purpose is to be inheritted.

Create your own entities (and make sure they inherit after superclasses) and then everything will work well.

Answer (score 0):

By default doctrine doesn't lookup into Model dir. At bundle build method, you need to specify custom mapping.

```
//src/NS/TestBundle/NSTestBundle.php
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $mappings = array(
            realpath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/doctrine/model') => 'NS\TestBundle\Model',
        );

    $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver($mappings));
}
```

Then Your mapped-superclasses will be properly interpredted

Comment: This was not an issue, indeed. I've found out that master-superclasses just cannot be exported what makes sense.